# How do I call C++ functions in JavaScript with WebKit?

Tags: javascript, c++, visual-studio, webkit

I'm trying to write a native Windows (pre-Metro) application that is almost entirely HTML/JavaScript. Some googling seemed to indicate that the ways to do this were:

1. QtWebKit
2. WebKit
3. Have Internet Explorer render it.

I don't want Qt as a dependency, so that rules out 1.
I need to write some native code (to interact with the OS), and make those functions available to be called in the JavaScript, so that rules out 3. But while it seems possible, I don't know how to do this in just WebKit.

Note: The build environment is Visual Studio, in case its relevant.

Comment: "While standing on my head, slapping myself in the face... How can I punch myself in the mouth?"

Comment: I never have used it but V8 seems to be able to generate machine code and it's really lightweight. http://code.google.com/p/v8/

Answer (score 2):

According to what you want to achieve, [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) is probably the best solution, have a look at a basic introduction

[Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started)

and you can also read about a guide about how to embed it

[Embedder's Guide](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed)

Comment: V8 doesn't render HTML and CSS though.

Comment: @Vanwaril or you can compile QT as static library so it's glued to your app and it's not a dependency.

Comment: That's still a code dependency even if not a user-facing one. I would rather not use it, and its not clear to me that this would be easier with QtWebKit than with just WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting MSHTML in a Windows app is relatively easy. To provide additional functions to the Javascript engine, just implement the IDocHostShowUI interface and return a IDipsatch through GetExternal().